# Try to do a global array

Tags: javascript

I'm display some elements with JSON

I have to post the next job on each iteration knowing that the first one is toto.

I have different array and try to push into a global array but don't know how to do

```
function getDataAjax(param) {
   var oXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

   var url = "https://.../" + param + "/api/json?pretty=true";
   oXhr.open('GET', url, true);
   oXhr.onload = function() {

      var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var Groups = new Array();
      var color = [];
      var Data = data.downstreamProjects.map(function(group) {

         if (group.name) {
            console.log(group.name);
            // rappel avec nouveau paramètre
            getDataAjax(group.name);
         }

         if (group.color == "blue") {
            color = "blue";
         } else if (group.color == "red") {
            color = "red";
         } else if (group.color == "notbuilt") {
            color = "gray";
         }

         var Group = new Array(group.name, color);
         Groups.push(Group);

      });

      console.log(Groups);
      sendAlerts(Groups);
   };

   oXhr.send(null);
}

// 1st appel
getDataAjax("toto");
```

Actual result :

- [['toto','blue']]
- [['titi','blue']]
- [['tata','blue']]

Expected rsult :

- [['toto','blue'],['titi','blue'],['tata','blue']]

Comment: Yes sorry, look again please thanks

Comment: Why do you have a recursive `getDataAjax` inside `if (group.name)`?

Comment: Because my first param is toto and thanks to the merhod DownStreamProject, I can push the next param (titi) and then do the same thing with titi who push the next param (tata)

Comment: I don't see how this relates to `jenkins`?

Comment: It's just because i'm using rst api from Jenkins, i'm using some job.
Toto, titi and tata are examples ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take declaration `var Groups = new Array();` outside of `getDataAjax(params)` function, Also console it after calling function `getDataAjax(params)` that is as follows

`var Groups = new Array();
getDataAjax("toto");
console.log(Groups);`